# Keyboard occupies TextFiled in Jetpack Compsoe

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-softkeyboard

I have textfield in Jetpack Compose, but when I go to another line to type keyboard occupies the text and I can not see what I am typing. [Video is attached]

[image]

Here is my TextField code:

```
TextField(
    value = userName,
            onValueChange = onTextChange,
            modifier = Modifier
                .widthIn(1.dp, Dp.Infinity)
                .onFocusChanged { focus = it.isFocused },
            colors = transparentTextFieldColors(),
            textStyle = typography.headlineLarge,
            placeholder = {
                Row(Modifier, Arrangement.Center, CenterVertically) {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(R.string.user_name),
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp),
                       
                    )
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_edit),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp),
                        tint = colorScheme.onTertiary
                    )
                }
            },
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
                onSaveUsername()
            },
            keyboardOptions = Default.copy(
                imeAction = Done,
                keyboardType = Text,
                capitalization = Sentences
            ),
            singleLine = true,
            visualTransformation = transformationOf(
                mask = ...,
                endChar = ...,
            ),
        )
```

I tried to specify android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" in my manifest, but it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

If your keyboard is overlapping in JetpackCompose you can simply use imePadding to avoid this issue,

[image]

Or if you want scrolling when your keyboard open then use vertical scrolling and add below line you manifest .

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**  // add this line in your manifest
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```